# Projecting a point in a segment : what if segment's extremities have a same coordinate?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, point, projection

Consider the following equality and instruction :

`p = ((x - a).(b - a))/((b - a).(b - a)) (b - a) + a`

Where `a` and `b` are the segment's extremities, `x` the point we want to project in this segment and `p` the projection of `x` in this segment. All are vectors-points.

Now the code that set `p`'s X coordinate :

```
            coords_p.add(
                ""
                        + (

                        ((test_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)) // "((x - a).(b - a))"
                                /
                                (// "((b - a).(b - a))"
                                        (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)

                                )

                                *
                                (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) // "* (b - a)"

                        +

                        segment_first_point_x) // " + a"
        );
```

Now, the same for `p`'s Y coordinate :

```
        coords_p.add(
                ""
                        + (

                        ((test_y - segment_first_point_y) * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y)) // "((x - a).(b - a))"
                                /
                                (0.00001+ // "((b - a).(b - a))"
                                        (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y) * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y)

                                )

                                *

                                (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y) // "* (b - a)"

                        +

                        segment_first_point_y) // " + a"

        );
```

As you can see, if `segment_last_point_y == segment_first_point_y` OR | `segment_last_point_x == segment_first_point_x`, the division's denominator will be `0`.

Thus, one (or both) of the `p`'s coordinates will be a `NaN` ("Not A Number") : it will be invalid.

So I think I didn't understand how to project a point... Could you enlighten me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi again :) The issue is in your computation of p, it shouldn't be *OR* as you describe, it should be *AND* because the denominator of the coefficient in the p formula is (b - a).(b - a). This should be 0 if and only if a and b are the same point, ie) you don't actually have a line segment.